# cygwin - Problems applying the Singleton pattern in Shared libraries

Tags: c++, singleton, cygwin, shared-libraries, extern

I'm using a binary in Cygwin/Windows where some libraries are loaded dinamically with `dlopen(path.c_str(), RTLD_LAZY);` but in this case, the C++ singleton pattern doesn't seem to work. Even if the main program initializes the singleton with a `Singleton::initInstance(some,params);` call, which sets a private `static Singleton* ptr;` field of the class, the shared library which calls the `Singleton::getInstance();` and then should retreive the `ptr` as an initialized values, it returns a `nullptr` instead. I've tried to solve the problem by defining a `Singleton *sharedsingleton;` in the main program that could be accessed in other modules with an `extern` call, but even in this case `sharedsingleton` seems to be `nullptr`. How could I solve my problem? I compile the libraries as follows:

```
INT_FILES := $(CPP_FILES:.cpp=.o)
OBJ_FILES := $(INT_FILES:.o=.plugin)
CC_FLAGS := -g -c  -std=c++11 -I../../src -I../../ext-libs -DWINDOWS
CC_SHARED := -shared -Wl,--export-all-symbols -Wl,--enable-auto-import -Wl,--export-all-symbols -Wl,--no-whole-archive ../../src/agent/*.o -Wl,--no-whole-archive ../../src/graph/*.o -Wl,--no-whole-archive ../../src/event/*.o -Wl,--no-whole-archive ../../src/plugin-loader/*.o -Wl,--no-whole-archive ../../src/*.o
CC_JSONO := ../../ext-libs/json/json.cpp

all:    $(INT_FILES) $(OBJ_FILES)

%.o:    %.cpp
    g++ $(CC_FLAGS) -o $@ $<

%.plugin:   %.o 
    g++ $(CC_SHARED) -o $@ $<
```

Thanks in advance (the same procedure seems to work under Linux, with different compilation flags (-fPIC and so on)).